# Reading vector<Mat> or Video ? (Opencv & C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I'm currently on a project where I have several picture taken with a camera.
My goal here is to make a video out of those pictures.
The problem is that pictures are not continuous ( there are some pictures missing in between).
And so when I'm trying to use Videowriter functions to create (obviously) a video the result is really messy and very speedy.
So I had an idea about creating an equivalent of a video reader but by reading a vector instead of a video: the display speed would depending on a cooldown between every pictures of my vector.
I would like to know your opinion about my solution and what would be your solution?
Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the FPS in the VideoWriter object,

```
VideoWriter video(videoname, CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), FPS, Size, true);
```

Try with FPS = 5 or even lesser, this might work